Can someone tell the api end point to be able to pause and start campaigns using amazon ads api?
Can someone tell the api end point to be able to pause and start campaigns using amazon ads api?
a small python snippet would be great.
I have been able to get a list of all campaigns.
not able to get the endpoint while reading documentation also.
